# how to stop postback on jquery tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, c#-4.0

i am using asp.net, C# and jquery tabs.my page Buttons in master page and in aspx page i am using content and with in the content,i made the tabs list. The problem is this when i am saving the page using  button. the postback is happening. page contains the 4 tabs and when i am on 4 tabs after saving it is going on first tab instead of tab 4. How to stop this Postback?

these are tabs

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"> Content 1 </div>
<div id="tabs-2"> Content 2 </div>
<div id="tabs-3"> Content 3 </div>
```

Comment: I think you should capture the state of tabs on button click

Comment: yes. i want to capture the state of tab. hw i can do this

Comment: The simplest of all is use the above code inside updatepanel, and to capture state you can use ViewState["variablename"] = State of tab and load in the page load

Comment: can u plz give me example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to keep in update panel however you have penalties regarding this for more info check this [link](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"> Content 1 </div>
<div id="tabs-2"> Content 2 </div>
<div id="tabs-3"> Content 3 </div>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden element the value of which you can set every time a tab is selected. On postback in the server side, you can capture this information to set the appropriate classes to the li element and the div element that is to be displayed on page reload. Else, simply maintain the state of the hidden variable and on initiation of the tabs in the client side on the page load, select the tab which is indicated in the hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to prevent postback to first tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.ctabs .ctab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            localStorage["currentTab"] = currentAttrValue;

            // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.ctabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

            // Change/remove current tab to active
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
        if (localStorage["currentTab"]) {
            // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.ctabs ' + localStorage["currentTab"]).show().siblings().hide();
            // Change/remove current tab to active
            jQuery('.ctabs .ctab-links a[href$="' + localStorage["currentTab"] + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```